# Was Lauryn McClain's character always supposed to end up like this?

Tags: character, casting, step-up, step-up-high-water

When *Step Up: High Water* started, Lauryn McClain as Janelle Baker seems like the main lead of the show and things were revolving around her but with time she got a clear exit and in the second season she never appeared.

Was Janelle Baker character always supposed to set up the pieces and never supposed to be the lead or it was changed due to unavailability of the actress or some behind the scene drama?